# How to round with modulus in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a input float that will be in the range `(-180,180]`, which means not including -180, but can include 180 (from Math.atan2). How can I round it to the nearest 10, but make sure that if it gets -180, it becomes 180 instead. Is there a way to do it without an `if` statement?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to avoid if statement? Because those kind of calculations what round degrees around typically have them.

Comment: mathematically you could define a function `f(x)` which returns `x` for all `x` except `x=-180`, it can return +180 for this value. But the problem is that for this you would have to use a delta function, which in practice translates to an `if` statement. For example, `f(x) = x + \delta(180 + x)`.

Answer (score 1):

This works, its just a way to avoid using if. There is no reason to do this.

```
function round(inp){
    var x = Math.round(inp/10)*10;
    return  x + !!!(x + 180)*360;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would you avoid if statement. Otherwise, it's just:

```
function roundDegrees(input) {
    var result = (Math.round(input/10)*10);
    return result==-180?180:result;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good answer to me. The title indicates that  the OP might want to  use a mod function to solve this - be careful as JavaScript's % operator for modulo calculations doesn't behave as you'd expect with negative numbers. There are other questions and answers on this topic on SO. This is one source that has been referred to: [The JavaScript Modulo Bug](http://javascript.about.com/od/problemsolving/a/modulobug.htm)